# How can I make Dropbox wait for Truecrypt? (including password input)

Tags: startup, dropbox, truecrypt

I am using Truecrypt to secure my data and am obliged to use Dropbox for some file sharing. I've set up my Dropbox folder on the Truecrypt mount.

When I log in Dropbox throws an error, because the Dropbox folder doesn't exist yet. I then have to mount the folder and restart Dropbox.

Is there any way that I can script the following:

- start Truecrypt, prompting to mount favorite volumes

  - cannot set a time for this as it's based on user input (I have to enter my admin password and Truecrypt password, and I must admit that sometimes I get distracted and make coffee while doing this)
- **only when volume is mounted**, start Dropbox
- options to do this automatically (on login) and manually

Comment: I don't have an answer but a suggestion: how about using [EncFS](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/06/encrypt-your-private-dropbox-data-with.html) instead of TrueCrypt? That seems a better way of handling this.

Comment: @alinandrei good suggestion, but in my case I want to the cross-platform compatibility offered by truecrypt

Comment: actually using an external tool called BoxCryptor, EncFS works on Windows and Android. I wrote how to get it to work on Android and in the same way it would work on Windows too (you need to tweak EncFS on Linux to be supported on the other platforms, but it works great).

Comment: @alinandrei in my situation someone else controls the Dropbox contents, I want to encrypt the Dropbox folder on my side - I guess I want Dropbox in my TrueCrypt, not TrueCrypt in my Dropbox - if I had more control over the situation I would certainly look into EncFS (or use SpiderOak :) ) - maybe this is a fool's errand and I shouldn't be trying to patch a leaky boat - interesting to learn if it's possible anyway, and I think your comments are valuable for anyone considering something similar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to do something quite similar. Here is what I ended up doing:

- remove Dropbox auto start feature of course
- have Ubuntu auto start the following script:

  ```
  #!/bin/bash
  #First let's check DB isn't running, you never know
  test "`dropbox status | awk '{print $2}'`" == "isn't" || exit;
  #mount private
  truecrypt --mount #you may optionally indicate which container you wish to mount
  #wait for truecrypt
  while test ! -d /media/truecrypt1/Dropbox
  do
      sleep 1
  done;
  #start DB
  dropbox start
  ```

Comment: accepting untested; I no longer need this, but this is the solution I would go for

Comment: @user127252 - This is a good answer. I would suggest a small improvement; use inotifywait to efficiently wait for the mounting.

Comment: @paddy-landau actually, [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1113176/how-could-i-detect-when-a-directory-is-mounted-with-inotify) suggests not

Answer (score 2):

You can add a script to delay Dropbox from starting up - the link to a dropbox forum question with the answer is [here](http://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=24743)

Comment: thanks, but the time is variable because I need to enter a password, I've updated the question to clarify this

Answer (score 2):

[iwatch](http://iwatch.sourceforge.net/index.html) is a commandline tool to allow you to monitor and respond to filesystem events using the **inotify** subsystem.  I'm not sure which event would be best but I would guess that some filesystem event occurs when a filesystem is mounted.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can parse to *df* output to discover if the volume is mounted. My Bash-foo is quite feeble, so here is a python script that should do it:

```
#! /usr/bin/python
# *-*coding=utf-8*-*

"""Try to start dropbox after some volume is mounted"""

import os
import time

MOUNT_POINT = "/home/javier/Private"

mounted = False
while not mounted:
    f = os.popen("df")
    for line in f:
        if MOUNT_POINT in line:
            mounted = True
    f.close()
    if not mounted:
        time.sleep(3000)
os.system('dropbox start')
```

You should change MOUNT_POINT to anything that df will output only when the volume is mounted.

I add a more pythonic way of doing it, but harder to port to bash and less flexible, it will need the real mount point.

```
#! /usr/bin/python
# *-*coding=utf-8*-*

"""Try to start dropbox after some volume is mounted"""

import os
import time

MOUNT_POINT = "/home/javier/Private"

mounted = False
while not mounted:
    if os.path.ismount(MOUNT_POINT):
        mounted = True
    else:
        time.sleep(3000)
os.system('dropbox start')
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following batch script. I use this in some of my own scripts that require some pieces I keep within a truecrypt container. Just throw the following in a .bat file. You will have to update some of the code depending on where you store your files and what not.

```
@echo off

IF EXIST "Z:\" (goto startDropBox)
"C:\Path\To\Truecrypt\truecrypt.exe" /v C:\Path\To\Truecrypt\Volume /lz /a /q

:startDropBox
C:\Path\To\DropBox\Executable\Dropbox.exe
```

The code assumes you always mount your volume on drive Z. From my experience, the code should hang at the truecrypt log-on screen before proceeding to the next part (running the dropbox executable).

To run this at startup, you could try replacing the dropbox shortcut in your startup folder with this batch file and you could run this manually if you wanted as well.

For other command line switches with Truecrypt look here:

http://www.truecrypt.org/docs/?s=command-line-usage

Hope that helps!

EDIT: Just realized this was an ubuntu forum, my bad! But could be nice for wandering Windows users *quickly hides*

Comment: you could post the same question and your answer on superuser.com

Comment: https://lifehacker.com/5794486/how-to-add-a-second-layer-of-encryption-to-dropbox

Answer (score 0):

The script should be something like this:

First, create it in your home. Added a dot at the beggining so it will be a hidden file:

```
gedit .dropboxdelayed
```

Then, paste this inside:

```
#!/bin/sh
#dropboxdelayed()
sleep 20 &&
dropbox start -i &
```

20 is the number of secconds of delay, don't know how much does truecrypt to mount your encrypted data so you should try it and adapt the number.

Give it permision to run:

```
chmod +x .dropboxdelayed
```

And create an entry pointing to it in System>Startup applications (remember to disable the other Dropbox entry there or you will be running two instances of it at the same time).

Whish it helps.

Comment: thanks, but the time is variable because I need to enter a password, I've updated the question to clarify this

Comment: Ok, even more easy: create the script but before the sleep line, add a line than launches truecrypt (sorry I can't help you with that, haven't used it, but it should end with one &). Then don't put the script in your startup but in a launcher or wherever you prefer. When you launch the script, you'll have 20 seconds to enter your password and when dropbox start, the drive will be allready mounted.